# Using redis to send friend status

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, socket.io

I was looking around the internet to find out how I can send user status such as offline and online, etc to only friends using socket io. Some people were saying to use Redis. so I had a look and played around with it. I am also using mongodb to store friends and users.

This is my setup right now:

```
//Status List: 
// 0 - offline
// 1 - online
// 2 - away
// 3 busy

//Set the status
redisClient.hmset ("online_status:userID", "status", "1");

//Check if someone is online
redisClient.hgetall ("online_status:userID", (err, reply) => {
  console.log(reply)
})
```

Is it fine if I use it like this to get user status? or is there a better way to do this?

Another question is that, is that is it fine to keep looping hgetall or is there a better way to get multiple statuses at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a hash type for storing a single information and you are using hgetall to retrieve it, so I assume you are not that familiar with redis data types yet. So first let me explain in short the three data types I'll talk about (find all types in the docs here https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro ):

- String: Is a simple key/value type, access it with `set(key, value)` and `get(key, value)`
- Hash: Is a bunch of key/values stored under one redis key. Useful for storing attributes of an entity, like you could have a "userdata:userID" key and store name, avatar, status... with it. Access it with `hset(key, field, value)`, `hget(key, field)`, `hgetall(key)`
- Set: Is a collection of unique strings, access it with `sadd(key, member)`, `sismember(key, member)`, `smembers(key)`

If you are only going to save the online status it would be cleaner to use a string type with set, get and del (since usually most users are offline most of the time, delete them and save space). For this simple key/value usecase redis is actually not even better than good old memcache.

If you intend to store more user related attributes (mood, motto, avatar...) you should rename it to "userdata:userID" and check with `hget("userdata:userID", "status")` and use `hgetall` only to retrieve *all* attributes.

Another approach could be to store all users in a SET: `sadd('users:online', userID)` and check with `sismember('users:online', userID)` or get all online users with `smembers('users:online')`. Suppose you store all friends in another SET `friends:userID`, you could grab all online friends of a user with a single intersect command `sinter('friends:userID', 'users:online')` - pretty nice and elegant IMHO, but this get's complicated with more different states and doesn't work with redis-cluster.

I would prefer the SET approach. Multiple hgets should also be fine until you encounter issues due to the one guy (there is allways one) that has thousands of contacts and refreshes all the time. At that point you could still introduce some friendship limits or caching.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I got a question though, I thought this was caching? Because I'm trying to use mongodb with redis. I also have another question. Is it fine to loop through an array of someone's friend list in mongodb, server side? I've always been scared to use loops in the server side.